# Mail stuck in drafts folder after migration from Hyper-V to ESXi

Tags: exchange-2010

One of my clients wanted a Hyper-V Exchange 2010 box to be moved to an ESXi box on a different subnet for several reasons. I ran the VMWare Converter from the Hyper V machine to the ESXi box and it all seems to have gone to plan.

When the box booted up I changed the network configuration to reflect the new subnet information, checked DNS to ensure the change was propagated, etc. I have noticed that my test e-mails from OWA do not send, but rather sit in the draft folder. Incoming e-mails also come as duplicates, but at least they reach the recipient.

The send connector looks correct (Type: SMTP, Address: *, Cost: 1, network : Use DNS Records to route mail automatically, and the source server is the local exchange server). The `test-servicehealth` cmdlet shows that there are all required services are running. Nothing of any use shows up in the Event Viewer.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve an issue like this?

EDIT : Running the `test-mailflow` cmdlet produces a failure, however it doesn't seem to indicate why that might be.

Comment: Any switch, VLAN, firewall or router changes needed to account for the new ip address?

Answer (score 1):

The issue described above appears to have been caused by the anti-spam software. After changing the IP settings, I re-checked them only to discover that they did not take. I added the new default gateway in the AS software, restarted the Exchange Mail Submission service and mailflow was restored.